# Change category H1 page title

Tags: category, page-title

I added custom field to the category admin. Now I can get this in viewer.

`<?php echo $_category->getInternalTitle() ?>`

But how to change default category H1 title(name) to this "internal_title"?

Answer (score 3):

Edit the template file `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` and replace the line:

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

with

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getInternalTitle(), 'internal_title') ?></h1>
```

Comment: Category title isn't to this file. It is some where outside